# Sequence field Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, sequence, odoo-12

I want to add a sequence field `"name"` that have this syntax : `"Alerte/date_creation/000x"`
it will be like :

```
"Alerte/14-07-2021/0001"
"Alerte/14-07-2021/0002"...
```

here my python code :

````
class StockAlert(models.Model):
    _name = "stock.alert"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'mail.activity.mixin']
    _rec_name = "name"

    name = fields.Char(string="Nom",default="New")
    date_creation = fields.Date("Date de création",default=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))```
````

Comment: Create a sequence with a number padding  of ``4`` and ``Alerte/%(day)s-%(month)s-%(year)s/`` as a prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities managed yourself via your own code (Bad idea) or used ir.sequence.

In the 2 cases, you will use method create

Managed yourself

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    res= super(YourClass, self).create(values)
    res.write({name : f'Alerte/{current_date}/{res.id}'})
    return res
```

This logic worked but you used 2 requests to doing this 1 Insert and 1 update.

Use ir.sequence

First in xml file you create a ir.sequence:

```
    <record id="seq_stock_alert" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Stock alert sequence</field>
        <field name="code">seq.stock.alert</field>
        <field name="prefix">Alerte/%(y)s-%(month)s-%(day)s/</field>
        <field name="padding">3</field>
    </record>
```

Next in your python

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    values['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('seq.stock.alert') or _('New')
    return super(YourClass, self).create(values)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,i used the second methode and it's working